C# clearing a list in a loop
I've got a Task that gets a list from SQL of all items that are not flagged, does stuff with that list, then sets a flag for those. Then it waits 5 seconds and pulls the list again. Instead of pulling the new list it keeps going through the existing list over and over and over.
I'm new to C#, and hoping someone has a way to do this better or how to actually clear the list and pull the new items.
public sealed class WindowsBackgroundService
(
    CheckIdScan idScanService, 
    ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> logger
) : BackgroundService
{
    bool debug = false;
    string sqlHost = "localhost";
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {  
        try
        {
            while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var MySQLconn = MySQLDbConn.Instance();
                MySQLconn.Host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
                MySQLconn.Database = "xxxx";
                MySQLconn.UserName = "xxxx";
                MySQLconn.Password = "xxxx"; 
                List<ScanModel> scans = idScanService.GetScans();
                foreach (ScanModel scan in scans)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (MySQLconn.IsConnect())
                        {
                            string insert = "insert into scans(siteCode,gender,age,hash,timeStamp) values(@siteCode,@gender,@age,@hash,@timeStamp)";
                           
                            MySqlCommand MySQLcmd = new(insert, MySQLconn.connection);
                            MySQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteCode", scan.siteCode);
                            MySQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", scan.gender);
                            MySQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", scan.age);
                            MySQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", scan.hash);
                            MySQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeStamp", scan.timeStamp);
                            MySQLcmd.Prepare();
                            try
                            {
                                MySQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch(Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.LogWarning("Error:{error}", ex.ToString());
                    }
                    if (!debug)
                    {
                        string sqlConnString = $"Server=tcp:{sqlHost};Database=xxxx;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Connection Timeout=60;TrustServerCertificate=True";
                        string updateSentQuery = "update scans set sent=1 where scanId=@scanId";
                        using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString))
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand())
                            {
                                sqlCmd.CommandText = updateSentQuery; 
                                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scanId", scan.scanId);
                                sqlConn.Open();
                                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                sqlConn.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                scans = new List<ScanModel>();
                
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogWarning("Error:{error}", ex.ToString());
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), stoppingToken);
    }
}

I verified that the "sent" flag is being set. If I end my task and run it again, it only pulls the ones not sent. So it seems like it's not actually clearing the list and pulling the list from SQL.
    public List<ScanModel> GetScans()
{
    if (!debug)
    {
        #region ReleaseScanList
        string connString = $"Server=tcp:{host};Database=piscan;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Connection Timeout=60;TrustServerCertificate=True;";
        string query = $"select scanID, gender, age, hash, sent, timeStamp from scans where sent=0";
     

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            #region GetVariables
                            try
                            {
                                scanId = (short)reader.GetInt16(reader.GetOrdinal("scanId"));
                            }
                            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidCastException($"ScanID:  {ex.Message}");
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                gender = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("gender"));
                            }
                            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidCastException($"Gender:  {ex.Message}");
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                age = (short)reader.GetInt16(reader.GetOrdinal("age"));
                            }
                            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidCastException($"Age:  {ex.Message}");
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                hash = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("hash"));
                            }
                            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidCastException($"Hash:  {ex.Message}");
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                timeStamp = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("timeStamp"));
                            }
                            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidCastException($"Time Stamp:  {ex.Message}");
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                sentInt = reader.GetInt16(reader.GetOrdinal("sent"));
                            }
                            catch(InvalidCastException ex)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidCastException($"Sent: Unable to get Int16 from database {ex.ToString()}"); 
                            }
                            try
                            { 
                                sent = Convert.ToBoolean(sentInt); 
                            }
                            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidCastException($"Sent: Unable to cast as boolean {ex.Message}");
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                siteCode = GetSiteCode();
                            }
                            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidCastException($"Site Code: {ex.Message}");
                            }
                            #endregion
                            scans.Add
                            (
                                new ScanModel
                                (
                                        scanId,
                                        gender,
                                        age,
                                        hash,
                                        sent,
                                        timeStamp,
                                        siteCode
                                )
                            );
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Could not connect to piscan {ex.Message} {ex.ToString()}");
        }
       
        #endregion
    }

    else
    {
        #region DebugScanList
        scans.Add
        (
            new ScanModel
            (
                1234,
                "M",
                48,
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP",
                false,
                DateTime.Now,
                siteCode
            )
        );
        
        #endregion
    }
    return scans;
}


I understand the question that your “list of items” is scans = idScanService.GetScans() and you keep getting the same list there? Then the answer to your question lies in the idScanService.GetScans method. The code you have shown is only responsible for updating some items but that won’t explain why you keep getting the same items.

@AndrewMorton MySQLcmd is recreated on every loop iteration, so there shouldn’t be anything shared from a previous call.

I added GetScans() it messed up the formatting a bit though :(

Good point, but it might be safer to use using for those new sqlcommands in the foreach loop.

Which btw parameters.clear() didnt work. Im assuming its because its already a new object
